# What does "much less forgiving reactions" mean?

Tags: meaning

I met the following sentence in a dictionary.

> In this respect, the outcomes of these cases may be contrasted with the much less forgiving reactions of juries in livestock theft prosecutions.

I'm a little confused by *much less forgiving reactions*. Does the author mean the reactions are forgiving or not forgiving? As I understand, *less* gives a negative sense, so *less forgiving* probably means *not forgiving*? But I doubt if I'm right. Hope someone could clarify a bit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the reactions are not forgiving, "much" modifies "less" in this usage. similar to if it were "even less forgiving". It indicates a smaller degree of forgiving.